# Does the regex engine have an associated executable?

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression, process, executable

I'm working with a tool that uses a whitelist to allow certain commands to be executed. The whitelist works using file paths like so:

- command1=/bin/echo
- command2=/bin/sed
- ...

The problem is commands like `sed` and `grep` are rejected by the whitelist if any regex expressions are used. Is there an executable associated with the regex engine that needs to be whitelisted here?

Comment: No. Matching regular expressions is either built into the executable (for historical reasons) or loaded from a shared library. Fix the "are rejected by the whitelist if any regex expressions are used" problem instead

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea why this might be happening? Unfortunately I don't have access to the source code of the tool and documentation is lacking.

Comment: What do you mean by "if any regex expression is used"? `foo` is a regexp. is `grep foo` rejected? Is `sed /foo/d` rejected? Is `sed s/foo/bar/g` rejected?  Is `echo foo` rejected? How is it rejected? Or is it that some strings with some characters (like `*`?) are rejected, or don't work as expected?

Comment: "if any regex expressions are used" What do you mean by that?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The examples you provided all work correctly. If any special characters are used e.g. `grep ^foo` the tool rejects the input with the error "Command not in whitelist." If I disable the whitelist feature, all commands run successfully. I suspect the issue is some internal parsing error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<strike>To the best of my knowledge, `sed` and `grep` implement their own regular expression engines. Browsing their source repositories, I see sed has [regexp.c](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/tree/sed/regexp.c), for instance.</strike>

There are many implementations of sed and grep, so the precise answer may vary depending on which one you're using, but in general, there probably isn't a regular expression executable to whitelist. Thanks to commenters for correcting me.

Comment: There are countless implementations of `sed` and `grep`, your link seems to be pointing to the GNU implementation of `sed`. The OP didn't mention they were on a GNU system (though even GNU systems often have more than one `sed` implementations like the GNU and busybox ones)

Comment: True and good point.

Comment: `sed` and `grep` arguably do _not_ implement regular expression engines but instead use the system's regular expression libraries.